# Unable to pass data to email template in Laravel

Tags: php, json, email, laravel

I am trying to send email to users with data retrieved from the database. The data is stored as a json file. However, I am unable to pass the data to the emaill template.

app/controllers/EmailController

```
<?php

class EmailController extends BaseController
{
    public function sendMail()
    {
//example of the json format        
$users_json =  
'[{"id":1,"first_name":"My","last_name":"Name","email":"my_name@gmail.com"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Your","last_name":"Name","email":"your_name@gmail.com"}]';

        $users = json_decode($users_json, true);

            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                Mail::send('message', $user, function($message) use ($user)
                {

                    $message->to($user['email'], $user['first_name'])
                            ->subject('Laravel Email Test 1');
                });

            }       
    }
}
```

app/views/message.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi {{ $first_name }}</h1>
<p>Yay it works! </p>   

</body>
</html>
```

The name passed to the template is returned as {{ $first_name }}.

```
Hi {{ $first_name }}

<Message starts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rename your message.php to message.blade.php but i'm not sure

Comment: For some reason it worked after changing the template name. Not sure if it is caused by the naming but will check.